# How get products from product table based on the category search in django restframework, How do inner join in django restframework

Tags: python, django, join, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am very much new in django restframework,I tried to create a search api.

I have 2 models designed

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    product_Status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_Description
```

I want to create a rest API, in which I can search the category and based on the search i want to list the product which related to that category. How can I do it.

My Views.py

```
class productList(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = productSerializer
   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = Product.objects.all()
       search = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
       if search is not None:
           queryset = queryset.filter(product_name__icontains=search)
```

my urls

```
path('product_search/',views.productList.as_view()),
```

Comment: Start by reading the Django Restframework documentation and create some [serializers](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/serializers.md) and [generic views](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/generic-views.md).

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need to add [filtering](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/filtering.md#filtering-against-query-parameters).

Also, you almost never need to override the `get()` method of a generic view. Look for the method that let's you do the least amount of work. For any view, you will do most work in `get_queryset` and a view specific method:

- List: view.`list()`
- Create: view.`create()`
- Retrieve: view.`retrieve()`
- Update: view.`perform_update()`
- Destroy: view.`perform_destroy()`

The rest can be customized by setting the correct class attributes. There are very few cases where it is necessary to override a view's "get" or "post" methods.

So, `get_queryset` is the place to modify the collection of objects that you are going to work on. This is perfect for filtering and thus search. A lot of work is already available in DRF and you can use it:

```py
class productList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = productSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        search = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
        if search is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__name__icontains=search)
        # don't forget to return the queryset
        return queryset
```

Comment: thanks, but its not hitting the url. my expected url is "product_search/?search=phone". here phone is a category and few products are in product table under category phone. I set category table as foreign key

Comment: Could you include your urls.py in the question?

Comment: I have updated the question. Also I dont want the search list based on the search on product name. I need on category name. When user input search key it should filter the cateogy list , and based on that category list need to get the product list

Comment: So if you put http://localhost:8000/product_search/?search=phone in your address bar, then you get a 404? Then you are probably missing a [piece of the url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). The 404 should explain it to you if you have DEBUG set to True in settings.

Comment: Okay, I will check but Iam getting field error cannot identify 'category'

Answer (score -1):

For filtering the Products based on category name is,

```
Product.object.filter( category__name = 'category_name')
```